# Extra dev peers in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the two org hyperledger [fabric example](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org). After starting the network I can see 4 extra dev peers running along with 4 peers(2 peers per org) in docker containers. But in configuration I gave only 4 peers. I am not understanding how the other 4 dev peers got created and whats their purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A specific 'Chain Code Container' gets created for each peer running the Business Network. E.g. `dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.3...`.  These containers are started and restarted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Chaincodes are instantiated in a separate container. When you instantiate a chaincode in a peer ,container for that chaincode is created.

If you instantiate  3 chaincode in a peer0 then you will see 3 containers with name like dev-peer0.mycc1, dev-peer0.mycc2,dev-peer0.mycc3

More details about this process can be found in an offical document mentioned below.(search text "dev-peer")

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/docs/source/build_network.rst